# Simplify $\frac{25!}{3!}$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I want to simplify the expression $\frac{25!}{3!}$. I understand that it doesn't make sense to do that because it's already simplified but can the answer be found out without writing all of the numbers out?

The easiest way to "solve" would be to write the whole thing out by hand and use a calculator to solve this problem but in a **non-calculator paper**, that would be impossible. I'm looking for a more efficient way to solve this question.

I've tried the easy way:

It's $$\frac{25!}{3!}=\frac{25*24*23*22*21*20*...*6*5*4*3*2*1}{3*2*1}=\frac{1.55...*10^{25}}{6}=2.85...*10^{24}$$

I think to simplify it, it would be $\frac{25!}{3!}=25!±6$ because you don't want to multiply the last three digits, $3,2,1$, of $25!$ But that doesn't give the right answer.

Can this be simplified any further?

Comment: What does solve mean?  Is writing it as a product good enough?

Comment: You can solve a problem, or an equation, but you can't solve an expression. You can calculate it (well, those who can can calculate it). It's just a big, uninteresting number (2585201673888497664000000), so why bother?

Comment: "I want to solve $\frac {25!}{3!}$"  Sure. It's the number you get when you multiply all the integers from one to twenty-five together and divide by 1times 2 times 3.  That's it.  It's solved.  Is there anything wrong with simply plugging into into your computers calculator?  I got $2585201673888497664000000$ in about two seconds.

Comment: "I think to simplify it, it would be $\frac {25!}{3!} = 25! \pm 6$"  Why would $\frac ab = a \pm b$????  "because you don't want to multiply the last three digits, 3,2,1, of 25!"  ???????  that is utterly incoherent and incomprensible.

Comment: @fleablood the question was in a non-calculator paper, meaning you're not allowed to use a calculator, which is mentioned in the question if you actually bothered to read it and not regurgitate what I already said.

Comment: Good question. You show a fair amount of work on your own part and are very clear about what you need and what you are confused about. "Solve" was the wrong word to use, but because of the context you provided it was clear what you meant. As such I'm not sure what all the fuss is about.

Comment: @amWhy What is wrong with this question? It is elementary but provides an ample amount of context. I have seen one sentence questions out here showing no context whatsoever get upvoted just because the subject matter is not elementary. Conversely, there are elementary questions such as this that are asked well and people have a problem with it.

Comment: The fuss is about what the word "solve" means and the incorrect, naive, and *wrong* idea that writing out a numerical answer is somehow a "solution".  The solution to $\frac {25!}{3!}$ is ... $\frac {25!}{3!}$.  That's it!  Nothing more is needed.  If the question was "calculate the decimal expansion of $\frac {25!}{3!}$ without using calculator" then I suggest you transfer to a different class because any instructor asking such a question is either an idiot or a sadist.  If the question is *estimate* the value that's a different question altogether.

Comment: To *simplify* the expression $\frac {25!}{3!}$ is already in simplest form.  Period.  If you need to express the numeric value for some reason then simply state it is 2585201673888497664000000.  In a "non-calculator paper" you don't need to explain how you calculate something $\frac {25!}{3!}=2585201673888497664000000$ is a perfectly acceptable statement; nothing more needs to be explained.

Comment: If on the other and the question is "give the unique prime factorization of $\frac {25!}{3!}$" then the answer is $2^{21}3^{9}5^6*7^3*11^2*13*17*19*23$.  If the question was approximate then it is yet another question. (See Abcd's answer or add up the logs of 1 through 25 and approximate those.)  But if the question is to "solve" or simplify, the answer is it *IS* already solved and simplified.

Comment: @wgrenard  I edited the question to make it slightly better; the asker posed the following question: "*Solve* $\frac{25!}{3!}$" and then proceeds merely to manipulate numbers, concluding the answer to be $$\frac{25!}{3!}=\frac{25*24*23*22*21*20*...*6*5*4*3*2*1}{3*2*1}=\frac{1.55...*10^{25}}{6}$$  How, they don't say.  Even after my edits to change "solve" to "simplify", there is no criteria given by the asker to measure "most simplified".  The answer posted received 7 questionable upvotes, when, as I comment under the answer, I'd consider $$\frac{25!}{6}$$ just as, if not more, simplified.

Comment: SkiMask  Your intuition about *a* simplified version of the expression involving $25!$ and $6$ is on target, but your version at the end is incorrect.  It is simply $$\frac{25!}{3!} = \frac{25!}{6}$$

Comment: The main problem here is that most commenters and voters don't understand what it is that the OP doesn't get and what an answer would look like. What we have here is a case of reverse Dunning Kruger. I'd be in favour of reopening this and trying to understand better what an acceptable answer would look like.

Comment: @SkiMask: "simplify" or "solve" is a rather vague term to use, which might be the reason why some  people are getting annoyed. It would be more appropriate if you use the phrase ["fraction in lowest terms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction) (if getting rid of the denominator is what you want). Besides, `@Abcd` has already answered your question if this is what you mean by "simplify".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\dfrac{25!}{3 !}= \dfrac{25\times 24\times23!}{6}= 100\times 23!$

Do you want its approximate value? 
If yes, you may then use the [Stirling's formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/stirling.html):

$$n!\approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2 \pi n} $$